# How long did the SR-71 take to get to cruising altitude?

Tags: aircraft-performance, climb, sr-71

How long did it take for the SR-71 to go from taking off to 80,000 ft, including refueling?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[According to the performance data in the manual](https://www.sr-71.org/blackbird/manual/appendix/a3-2.php) it takes 19.9 minutes to get to 70,600 feet.

[image]

Refueling time will depend on how much fuel is needed for the mission as well as how long it takes to hook up to the tanker. [The manual covers the operations for that](https://www.sr-71.org/blackbird/manual/2/2-54.php) but  I dont see a flow rate of fuel in there. [A lot of that stuff is covered in this podcast.](https://omegataupodcast.net/91-flying-the-sr-71/)

Comment: @bogl good catch, I have updated.

Comment: That's an average ROC of 3,500 fpm.  Or to put it another way, the vertical component alone of the climb is 35 knots!  That must have been like riding a tiger.

Comment: @WayneConrad, you should listed to the linked podcast, most of the backbird pilots note that aside from the high landing/approach speed the plane did not really feel that fast due to the altitude and lack of close references as you climb.I think the exact quote was "you get a greater sensation of speed at 500 ft above ground in a piper cub"

Comment: That makes sense.  Wilco, thanks.

Comment: Chapter 4 of "SR-71 Revealed" by Richard Graham states that refueling rates from both the KC-10 and KC-135Q were 6,000 lbs per minute.  He ballparks 15 minutes for a full refuel, though it seems like the operational details on refueling varied a lot per-mission, and even a single refueling rendezvous may have involved refueling from more than tanker operating in a "cell".